# Remove string upto the first occurrence of a character using batch script

Tags: string, batch-file

I have a variable say

```
var="dev02,qa02,stage,prod,dev02_loc,qa02_loc,stage_loc,prod_loc"
```

I need to convert this into

```
qa02,stage,prod,dev02_loc,qa02_loc,stage_loc,prod_loc
```

by removing all the characters before the first occurence of `,`

How can I do this using batch script?

Comment: You should first see the instructions on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check out `for /?`, specifically the `for /f` section and the part about `tokens`.

Comment: [::Delete the character string 'ab' and everything before it](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: As a side note to the link above, for setting your initial variable, `%var%`, you should change the syntax to this: `Set "var=dev02,qa02,stage,prod,dev02_loc,qa02_loc,stage_loc,prod_loc"`

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is to use variable expansion and substitution.

In this case given your stated variable content of:

```bat
dev02,qa02,stage,prod,dev02_loc,qa02_loc,stage_loc,prod_loc
```

You could simply expand the variable, substituting everything up to the first comma with nothing:

```bat
Echo(%var:*,=%
```

---

For setting your initial variable, `%var%`, you should change the syntax to this:

```bat
Set "var=dev02,qa02,stage,prod,dev02_loc,qa02_loc,stage_loc,prod_loc"
```

This will prevent the doublequotes from being included in the variable value, prevent accidental trailing whitespace and protect the content.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `for` loop (see `for /?`) `delimit` on `,` and do something with the result:

```
@set "var=dev02,qa02,stage,prod,dev02_loc,qa02_loc,stage_loc,prod_loc"
@for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%i in ("%var%") do @echo(%%j
```

Comment: In situations where you do not know (or define) the var beforehand it's not safe to assume `%%j` **has** a value - so I'd `@echo(%%j` to avoid echo status being returned.